# Is there option to hide header on first page and show remaining page based on page number in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services

I have reset the page number in header section. I can't access the page number in report body section.Is there any custom code to reset the page number by grouping in SSRS. Help me to sort out from this issue.

Comment: Check this link https://www.cloudfronts.com/how-to-reset-page-number-in-footer-after-page-break/

Answer (score 0):

you can right click on  header => choose header properties uncheck print on first page